# Resources for improving storytelling

Tags: resources, narrative

I mainly write fiction, but want to improve my storytelling techniques. I'm looking for some books or resources to improve this. I want study different story structures and storytelling techniques. I enjoy the video of Vonnegut describing shapes of stories and would enjoy something that describes something similar.

Comment: +1 to the Sanderson recommendation below. WSE (here) is good. In-person groups are good - you will get feedback on your work in real time.

Answer (score 3):

Brandon Sanderson has you covered! [Series on YouTube detailing everything he talks about in his lectures.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4ZDBOc2tX8&list=PLH3mK1NZn9QqOSj3ObrP3xL8tEJQ12-vL)

There are another dozen-odd YouTubers that discuss everything Brandon does, in their own way, and with their own touch added in.

Think [Shaelin Writes](https://www.youtube.com/user/ShaeTheWordNerd), [Diane Callahan](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEmQO4-dP2XhINMXnad6E7g), [Francina Simone](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcUVLS6cM_JiEHHXsmsqwrA) (though she also talks about a lot of other stuff, all quite interesting), and [Just Write](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCx0L2ZdYfiq-tsAXb8IXpQg) to name a few.

For broader storytelling theme (no direct focus on writing, but more for TV and the silver screen), there's also [Film Courage](https://www.youtube.com/user/filmcourage). But keep in mind, they talk about movies, and therefore it doesn't always translate the right way into novel format. But, I find their talks very enlightening all the same.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the more stories you read, the better your storytelling becomes.

Obviously it works better when you read stories in the same genre/scenario as your story, as the writing is more relevant.

For example, if you're writing (dark) dystopian fiction, you could read Derek Landy (Skullduggery Pleasant and The Demon Road), Michael Grant (BZRK and the GONE series), and possibly Dan Brown and Anthony Horowitz.

This helps as you naturally fall into the same style of writing, the same level of maturity, the same sort of atmosphere etc. (For example, I found that after doing this, useful well-written phrases naturally spring to mind (due to reading such high-quality relevant literature).